# Deploying to heroku play framework java

Tags: java, heroku, deployment, playframework

I get this error when deploying my play 2.3 java project. This is my first time deploying

```
 [info] Set current project to scala_buildpack_build_dir (in build file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/)
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2014 1:29:13 AM
   [info] Updating {file:/tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/}scala_buildpack_build_dir...
   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.4 ...
   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.10.4 ...
   [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 ...
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 4, 2014 1:29:13 AM
   [error] Not a valid command: stage (similar: last-grep, set, last)
   [error] Not a valid project ID: stage
   [error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
   [error] Not a valid key: stage (similar: state, target, tags)
   [error] stage
   [error]      ^
```

!     Failed to build app with sbt

Comment: You can read more about play gist and deploy using play executable.